# t-test and computing p-values in R

Tags: r

> There is a data set "Wine" from pack "candisc". The task is to compare "grignolino" and "barbera" in turms of their parameter AlcAsh with the use of t-test. What is the p-value? The answer is to be given with rounding to the fifth digit.

I took an attempt to solve the task, here is the code.

```
dat<-Wine[Wine$Cultivar == c('grignolino', 'barbera'), ]
tt<-t.test(AlcAsh~Cultivar, dat)
tt$p.value
[1] 0.01467608
```

> The p-value was computed incorrectly. 
>   What the problem might be?

Comment: At the least the subsetting is not correct.  Use `%in%` not `==`.  You can also subset as part of the `t.test()` function (if using the formula interface) - `t.test(AlcAsh~Cultivar, Wine, subset = Cultivar %in% c('grignolino', 'barbera'))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LOL lots of possibilities lets start with:

```r
dat<-Wine[Wine$Cultivar %in% c('grignolino', 'barbera'), ]
tt<-t.test(AlcAsh~Cultivar, dat, var.equal = TRUE)
tt$p.value
[1] 0.03519209
tt<-t.test(AlcAsh~Cultivar, dat, var.equal = FALSE)
tt$p.value
[1] 0.02365085
```

or could be it's one-sided or ...

Comment: your sub-setting is not correct, you have to use `%in%` and not `==`.

Comment: You're right, got side-tracked between Student and Welch, didn't notice the `==` was not failing but producing a bad slice

Comment: no problem, thanks for fixing that, I removed the downvote